# Citations are mentioned separately, not in a group?

Tags: hyperref, citing, natbib, elsarticle

I am using "elsarticle" document class, and `chapterbib` and `hyperref` for citations.

When I group the citation, instead of getting a range in the text, I get all of them mentioned separately.

For example:

```
\cite{p8,p15,p21,p48,p50,p57,p59,p60,p71}
```

I need to get `[1]-[9]`. But the result is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`.

Could anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the option `sort&compress` when executing `\documentclass`. This option will be passed to the `natbib` package, which is loaded automatically by the `elsarticle` document class.

An MWE (minimum working example):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib} % create 9 dummy bib entries
@misc{p08, author = "a", title = "b", year = "c" }
@misc{p15, author = "a", title = "b", year = "c" }
@misc{p21, author = "a", title = "b", year = "c" }
@misc{p48, author = "a", title = "b", year = "c" }
@misc{p50, author = "a", title = "b", year = "c" }
@misc{p57, author = "a", title = "b", year = "c" }
@misc{p59, author = "a", title = "b", year = "c" }
@misc{p60, author = "a", title = "b", year = "c" }
@misc{p71, author = "a", title = "b", year = "c" }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % choose a suitable bibliography style

\begin{document}
\cite{p08,p15,p21,p48,p50,p57,p59,p60,p71}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```